# JavaScript - ¿Como puedo obtener la frecuencia de un sonido en tiempo real?

Tags: javascript, frecuencia

Alguien podría darme una pista de como obtener la frecuencia de un sonido en tiempo real con javascript? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La API disponible para hacer esto es [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext), necesitas hacer 4 cosas:

1. Crear un nodo analizador, que te permite tomar muestras del audio por pedazos y saber, por ejemplo, la intensidad de la señal en cada punto.
2. Crear un nodo procesador, que te permite procesar el audio a medida que se reproduce.
3. En el procesador, y utilizando el analizador, tomas las muestras de frecuencia.
4. Conectar todo junto para: Visualizar la intensidad actual del audio y enviarlo también al speaker o output.

Con las muestras de frecuencia (obtenidas con transformada rapidad de Fourier o FFT) puedes buscar las frecuencias con mayor intensidad y determinar la frecuencia dominante. Hay [muchos métodos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm#Frequency-domain_approaches) para calcular el pitch, aquí he utilizado una muy simple y no muy preciso que se basa en la señal con mayor energía, pero el oído humano no funciona de esta forma, por lo que puede requerir cierto trabajo adaptar el calculo de la frecuencia "audible"..

El ejemplo esta en este [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/reLsxaht/5/), por que los StackSnippets no permiten capturar el microfono. Fijate que la linea verde es la frecuencia que se muestra arriba. Funciona bastante bien con un generador de tonos como [este](http://jsfiddle.net/aqilahmisuary/ztf5a72h/#base).

Ten en cuenta que son APIs bastante nuevas y aunque hay buen soporte es una opcion que te conviene usarla como Progressive Enhancement, osea que solo deberias incluirla en navegadores que lo soportan. Tambien es muy util en aplicaciones hechas con Electron o Apache Cordoba ya que se basan en Chromium y este soporta estas APIs muy bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora probare eso!

Comment: Veo que al probar, no me detecta la frecuencia, me podrías explicar un poco mas como adaptar eso?

Comment: Hola @JosephAlbertoMorthimerLeon, diculpa tenia un compromiso y ahora ya se hizo tarde. Mañana en algun momento me tomare el tiempo de modificar el ejemplo y de explicarlo. Gracias x la paciencia! Salu2

Comment: @JosephAlbertoMorthimerLeon tengo una pregunta, cuando te refieres a la frecuencia, hablas Khz verdad? algo asi como un afinador de guitarras o similar. O en cambio te refieres a graficar la señal como lo hace un reproductor?

Comment: Hola disculpa la demora, claro me refiero a los Khz!. Espero me puedas ayudar. Gracias! @rnd

Comment: @JosephAlbertoMorthimerLeon no es algo factible de obtener pues en un audio hay muchos sonidos a la vez a diferentes frecuencias y entonces ¿que reagla usar para elejir el sonido?. Salvo que tengas un sonido puro o de por ejemplo un instrumento musical (donde hay armonicos)... Por eso, puedes explicarme un poco mas que intentas hacer? osea, cual seria la aplicacion asi voy directo al grano? gracias!

Comment: Hola de nuevo, lo que solo quiero obtener las frecuencia de una voz, o un instrumento por micrófono.

Comment: @JosephAlbertoMorthimerLeon fijate que he editado la pregunta.